# OBEngine Service missing from a fresh install of Azure Backup

Tags: azure

I downloaded the MS Azure Recovery Agent from the portal and registered and set up the server fine

I set up a quick backup job to test and when I came to run it I get the following error:

I have rebooted the server and still the same error

[image]

The service is missing so i guess that's why it won't run but I cant see or find how to get that service installed.
I would not have expected this issue from a clean install?

Anyone help please?